# Supremum of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, supremum-and-infimum, discrete-geometry

For a non-empty compact set C ⊂ R (or $R^2$) prove that there is the point x ∈ C such that y *<lex* x for any y ∈ C\ {x}.

From the analysis, we know that supremum of any subset of R exits. And since C is a compact set (i.e it is bounded and closed) therefore its supremum belongs to C. Let x = sup C. Then there is a sequence of number i.e. $y_1,y_2,..y_n$ ∈ C. So the limit $y_i$ = x, and due to the closeness x ∈ C.
This is what I have tried in case of R but I am not sure if it's correct or do I have to include something else and am unable to do so for $R^2$. Any kind of feedback is appreciated?

Note: '**<lex**' denotes the lexicographic ordering by their co-ordinate vertices...i.e. X <lex Y if $x_1=y_1, \ x_2=y_2 ... , x_i< y_i$. where X =($x_1,x_2...x_d$) and Y =($y_1,y_2...y_d$) and i ∈ [d]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @MartinR Oh! thank you so much. I was actually struggling.

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you tried for $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @subrosar I have added what I kind of tried for R. I not very confident about but this is the only thing I was able to. Please if you think I need to do something extra, please let me know

Comment: Not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum, just the bounded ones. But if you know that compact sets are bounded, then $C$ has a bound and therefore a supremum, so you are fine. We don't automatically know that $x$ belongs to $C$, but it seems like this is what you are proving with the limit. Because $C$ is compact it must be closed and contain all of its limit points. We know the supremum of $C$ is the limit of some sequence of numbers in $C,$ so the supremum is a limit point and must be contained in $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Let $\pi_1:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x$ and $\pi_2:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto y$ be the projection maps to the coordinate axes. Show that $\pi_1[C]$ has a maximum element, say $a$. Then show that $\{y\in\Bbb R:\langle a,y\rangle\in C\}$ has a maximum element, say $b$. Finally, show that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is the maximum element of $C$ in the lexicographic order on $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: I actually have no idea about projection mapping. Can we do it with normal mapping. I am kind of new to this

Comment: like I have few ideas about real analysis not much in depth and a little basics on topology. So it's kind of difficult for me.

Comment: The projection map is just a map $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that takes a pair $(x,y)$ and returns one coordinate, say the second. In this case, $\pi_2(x,y)=y.$

Comment: @Dasha: The projections are just ordinary functions — rather nice ones, though, since they are continuous. $\pi_1[C]$ is just the set of all $x$-coordinates of points of $C$, and $\pi_2[C]$ is just the set of all $y$-coordinates of points of $C$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  so are you saying that that b is the maximum element of  $π_2[C]$ or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And we can show that (a,b) belongs to C by using the closeness property as I did for C ⊂ R?

Comment: @Dasha: $b$ need not be the maximum element of $\pi_2[C]$, but it **is** the maximum element of $\pi_2[\{a\}\times\Bbb R$. $C$ could, for instance, be $([0,1]\times[0,2])\cup\{\langle 2,1\rangle$; this is compact in the lexicographic order topology, $\pi_2[C]=2$, and $b=1$. \\ Yes, the fact that $C$ is closed allows you to conclude that $\langle a,b\rangle\in C$.